# F# pattern matching with generic types. Possible?

Tags: generics, types, parameters, functional-programming, f#

I have the following code:

```fsharp
[<AbstractClass>]
type Effect<'a>() =
    class end

type Input<'a>(chan : Channel<'a>, cont : 'a -> Effect<'a>) = 
    inherit Effect<'a>()
    member this.Chan = chan
    member this.Cont = cont

type Output<'a>(value : 'a, chan : Channel<'a>, cont : unit -> Effect<'a>) =
    inherit Effect<'a>()
    member this.Value = value
    member this.Chan = chan
    member this.Cont = cont

type Parallel<'a, 'b>(eff1 : Effect<'a>, eff2 : Effect<'b>) =
    inherit Effect<'a * 'b>()
    member this.Eff1 = eff1
    member this.Eff2 = eff2

type Return<'a>(value : 'a) =
    inherit Effect<'a>()
    member this.Value = value

let Send(value, chan, cont) = Output(value, chan, cont)
let Receive(chan, cont) = Input(chan, cont)

let rec NaiveEval (eff : Effect<'a>) =
    match eff with 
    | :? Input<'a> as input           -> ()
    | :? Output<'a> as output         -> ()
    | :? Parallel<'a, 'b> as par      -> () // ERROR: FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type 'Parallel<'a,'b> is not compatible with type 'Effect<'a>'.
    | :? Return<'a> as ret            -> ()
    | _                               -> failwith "Unsupported effect!"
```

I want to be able to pattern match in some way on the different subclasses of Effect as seen in the NaiveEval function. The pattern match on **Parallel<'a, 'b>** gives the following error:

> FS0193: Type constraint mismatch. The type 'Parallel<'a,'b> is not compatible with type 'Effect<'a>'.

I would assume that in this case **'a** would be inferred to be **'a * 'b** but I guess that is not what's happening.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT to Mark's answer:**

So as far as I understand, what I am trying to do is not possible. I started out with a discriminated union, but I thought the type hierarchy would fix my issue. I guess not.

I used this union before:

```ml
type Effect<'a> =
     | Input of Channel<'a> * ('a -> Effect<'a>)
     | Output of 'a * Channel<'a> * (unit -> Effect<'a>)
     | Parallel of Effect<'a> * Effect<'a>
     | Return of 'a
```

I used to use this type, but I wanted to parallel to be: Parallel of Effect<'a> * Effect<'b> and not just both 'a. I assume this is not possible either?

Comment: What you're after isn't really possible - you can't create a different type parameter ad-hoc like this and also have it recursively defined like that. The `'b` has to come from somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the type parameter in `Parallel` is defined as corresponding to `'a * 'b`. In other words, the single type parameter of `Effect<'a>` is here `'a * 'b`.

Perhaps it's easier to understand how these correspond if you rename the type variables to `'b` and `'c`:

```
type Parallel<'b, 'c>(eff1 : Effect<'b>, eff2 : Effect<'c>) =
    inherit Effect<'b * 'c>()
    member this.Eff1 = eff1
    member this.Eff2 = eff2
```

Now you have that in the `Parallel` case, `'a = 'b * 'c`.

The compiler error is exactly because you're trying to redefine what `'a` is. Essentially, you're trying to insist that `'a = 'a * 'b`. This doesn't work because you have `'a` on both sides of the equals sign.

(We could imagine a more sophisticated type system that would allow this. This would essentially be like saying that `x = x + y`, which is only possible if `y = 0`. In the world of algebraic data types, this would imply that `'b` would be `()` (`unit`)... but the F# type system can't infer that, and in any case it's probably not what you want.)

You can exchange the error for a compiler warning by explicitly using the renamed type arguments:

```
let rec NaiveEval (eff : Effect<'a>) =
    match eff with 
    | :? Input<'a> as input           -> ()
    | :? Output<'a> as output         -> ()
    | :? Parallel<'b, 'c> as par      -> () // Warning FS0064
    | :? Return<'a> as ret            -> ()
    | _                               -> failwith "Unsupported effect!"
```

The warning, however, is:

> This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'a has been constrained to be type ''b * 'c'.

In other words, the `NaiveEval` function can only evaluate `Effect<'b * 'c>` - probably still not what you want..?

This may still be a little difficult to accept, but imagine that you'd want to *do* something with `par` in the `Parallel` case. This, for example, doesn't compile because, once again, the types don't line up:

```
| :? Parallel<'b, 'c> as par      ->
    NaiveEval (par.Eff2)
```

Here, `par.Eff2` has the type `'c`, but you're currently 'inside' a function of the type `Effect<'b * 'c> -> unit`. You can't recurse into it, and compiler tells you so:

> Error FS0001 The types ''c' and ''b * 'c' cannot be unified.

---

BTW, have you considered defining a discriminated union instead of a type hierarchy?

Comment: Hi Mark. I've updated my question above.

Comment: @Iyyel, generics exist at compile-time, so you can't just conjure a new type argument out of thin air. In Haskell, you might be able to get around this with a GADT or rank-n type. Depending on what you need to do, you may be able to get around some of these issues with rank-n types or existential types, which are also possible on .NET, but those are quite advance techniques...

Comment: I think an old fashioned visitor may do the job.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd [Visitor is isomorphic to sum types](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/25/visitor-as-a-sum-type) (discriminated unions).

Comment: certain tagless encodings admit extension, which F# sum types dont. So isomorphism is a bit strong, i.e. i can write code in a tagless style that I can't map to standard F# DUs.

Comment: maybe best map the below answer into a DU

Answer (score 0):

I have many moons ago dug into tagless encodings, but I can't seem to get this to work in this context (actually i do further down).

I got something to work using good old fashioned and underated visitor pattern (which is closely related, excuse my idiosyncratic F# its been a while, I think my method signatures should be tupled really, but i dont do that until the final version).

foo outputs 6, and recursively evaluates a parallel effect.

```
type Channel<'a>() = class end

type IEffectVisitor<'ret> =
    abstract member VisitInput<'a> : Input<'a> -> 'ret
    abstract member VisitOutput<'a> : Output<'a> -> 'ret
    abstract member VisitParallel<'a,'b> : Parallel<'a,'b> -> 'ret 
    abstract member VisitReturn<'a> : Return<'a> -> 'ret
and IEffect<'a> = 
    abstract member Accept<'ret> : IEffectVisitor<'ret> -> 'ret
and Input<'a>(chan : Channel<'a>, cont : 'a -> IEffect<'a>) = 
    interface IEffect<'a> with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitInput(this)
    member this.Chan = chan
    member this.Cont = cont
and Output<'a>(value : 'a, chan : Channel<'a>, cont : unit -> IEffect<'a>) =
    interface IEffect<'a> with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitOutput(this)
    member this.Value = value
    member this.Chan = chan
    member this.Cont = cont
and Parallel<'a, 'b>(eff1 : IEffect<'a>, eff2 : IEffect<'b>) =
    interface IEffect<'a> with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitParallel(this)
    member this.Eff1 = eff1
    member this.Eff2 = eff2
and Return<'a>(value : 'a) =
    interface IEffect<'a> with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitReturn(this)
    member this.Value = value

let rec NaiveEval (eff : IEffect<'a>) : int =
    eff.Accept(
        { new IEffectVisitor<int> with
            member this.VisitOutput x = 
                1
            member this.VisitParallel x =                     
                x.Eff1.Accept(this) + x.Eff2.Accept(this)
            member this.VisitReturn x = 
                3
            member __.VisitInput x = 
                4 })

let foo() = 
    let x = Parallel(Return 1, Return "a")
    printfn "%A" <| NaiveEval(x)
    ()
```

---

actually thinking about this, I went back to it, you can lose the type parameter on the effect all together without (in the example) any loss of type safety, and this paves the way for a more tagless like implementation.

```
type Channel<'a>() = class end

type IEffectVisitor<'ret> =
    abstract member VisitInput<'a> : Input<'a> -> 'ret
    abstract member VisitOutput<'a> : Output<'a> -> 'ret
    abstract member VisitParallel<'a,'b> : Parallel -> 'ret 
    abstract member VisitReturn<'a> : Return<'a> -> 'ret
and IEffect = 
    abstract member Accept<'ret> : IEffectVisitor<'ret> -> 'ret
and Input<'a>(chan : Channel<'a>, cont : 'a -> IEffect) = 
    interface IEffect with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitInput(this)
    member this.Chan = chan
    member this.Cont = cont
and Output<'a>(value : 'a, chan : Channel<'a>, cont : unit -> IEffect) =
    interface IEffect with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitOutput(this)
    member this.Value = value
    member this.Chan = chan
    member this.Cont = cont
and Parallel(eff1 : IEffect, eff2 : IEffect) =
    interface IEffect with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitParallel(this)
    member this.Eff1 = eff1
    member this.Eff2 = eff2
and Return<'a>(value : 'a) =
    interface IEffect with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitReturn(this)
    member this.Value = value


module Foo = 
    let Send(value, chan, cont) = Output(value, chan, cont)
    let Receive(chan, cont) = Input(chan, cont)

    let rec NaiveEval (eff : IEffect) : int =
        eff.Accept(
            { new IEffectVisitor<int> with
                member this.VisitOutput x = 
                    1
                member this.VisitParallel x =                     
                    x.Eff1.Accept(this) + x.Eff2.Accept(this)
                member this.VisitReturn x = 
                    3
                member __.VisitInput x = 
                    4 })

    let foo() = 
        let x = Parallel(Return 1, Return "a")
        printfn "%A" <| NaiveEval(x)
        ()
```

which leads you onto something a bit tagless....(I always love this bit, becuase of the realisation that a factory pattern is actually a special case of a visitor - in a way, and all your classes and DUs evaporate into functions/methods).

```
type Channel<'a>() = class end

type IEffectAlgebra<'retInput,'retOutput,'retParallel,'retReturn> =
    abstract member Input<'a> : Channel<'a> * ('a -> IEffect) -> 'retInput
    abstract member Output<'a> : 'a * Channel<'a> * (unit -> IEffect) -> 'retOutput
    abstract member Parallel<'a,'b> : IEffect * IEffect -> 'retParallel
    abstract member Return<'a> : 'a -> 'retReturn
and IEffect = 
    abstract member Accept<'ret> : IEffectAlgebra<'ret,'ret,'ret,'ret> -> 'ret

type IEffectVisitor<'ret> = IEffectAlgebra<'ret,'ret,'ret,'ret>
type IEffectFactory = IEffectVisitor<IEffect>

let effectFactory = 
    { new IEffectFactory with
        member __.Input(arg1, arg2) = 
            { new IEffect with 
                member __.Accept(v) = v.Input(arg1, arg2) }
        member __.Output(arg1, arg2, arg3) = 
            { new IEffect with 
                member __.Accept(v) = v.Output(arg1, arg2, arg3) }
        member __.Parallel(arg1, arg2) = 
            { new IEffect with 
                member __.Accept(v) = v.Parallel(arg1, arg2) }
        member __.Return(arg1) = 
            { new IEffect with 
                member __.Accept(v) = v.Return arg1 }
    }

module Foo = 
    let Send(value, chan, cont) = effectFactory.Output(value, chan, cont)
    let Receive(chan, cont) = effectFactory.Input(chan, cont)

    let rec NaiveEval (eff : IEffect) : int =
        eff.Accept(
            { new IEffectVisitor<int> with
                  member __.Input(_, _) = 1
                  member __.Output(_, _, _) = 2
                  member this.Parallel(arg1, arg2) = 
                    arg1.Accept this + arg2.Accept this
                  member __.Return(_) = 4 })

    let foo() = 
        let x = effectFactory.Parallel(effectFactory.Return 1, effectFactory.Return "a")
        printfn "%A" <| NaiveEval(x)
        ()
```

---

so for the Return<> requirement lets keep in simple with the visitor, and introduce what I think is known as a phantom type.
See naiveeval2, ignore the exception code...I don't know what your code actually does, the type knot is processing the Parallel type and the return type...its not typesafe, you have to fold over the Effect structure into an obj, and then cast the result. I think its impossible for this code to actually fail (in terms of types) if your Effect types are typesafe, I just can't see a way for the F# compiler to verify that in the types, it feels like it may need GADTs (which we can't do)...but I suspect an expert Haskeller will tell us different...I'm a very inexpert haskeller.

```
type Channel<'a>() = class end

type IEffectVisitor<'ret> =
    abstract member VisitInput<'a> : Input<'a> -> 'ret
    abstract member VisitOutput<'a> : Output<'a> -> 'ret
    abstract member VisitParallel<'a,'b> : Parallel<'a,'b> -> 'ret 
    abstract member VisitReturn<'a> : Return<'a> -> 'ret
and IEffect<'a> = 
    abstract member Accept<'ret> : IEffectVisitor<'ret> -> 'ret
and Input<'a>(chan : Channel<'a>, cont : 'a -> IEffect<'a>) = 
    interface IEffect<'a> with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitInput(this)
    member this.Chan = chan
    member this.Cont = cont
and Output<'a>(value : 'a, chan : Channel<'a>, cont : unit -> IEffect<'a>) =
    interface IEffect<'a> with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitOutput(this)
    member this.Value = value
    member this.Chan = chan
    member this.Cont = cont
and Parallel<'a,'b>(eff1 : IEffect<'a>, eff2 : IEffect<'b>) =
    interface IEffect<'a * 'b> with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitParallel(this)
    member this.Eff1 = eff1
    member this.Eff2 = eff2
and Return<'a>(value : 'a) =
    interface IEffect<'a> with
        member this.Accept(v) = v.VisitReturn(this)
    member this.Value = value


module Foo = 
    let Send(value, chan, cont) = Output(value, chan, cont)
    let Receive(chan, cont) = Input(chan, cont)



    let rec NaiveEval (eff : IEffect<_>) : int =
        eff.Accept(
            { new IEffectVisitor<int> with
                member this.VisitOutput x = 
                    1
                member this.VisitParallel x =                     
                    x.Eff1.Accept(this) + x.Eff2.Accept(this)
                member this.VisitReturn x = 
                    3
                member __.VisitInput x = 
                    4 })


    let rec NaiveEval2 (eff : IEffect<'a>) : 'a =
        eff.Accept(
            { new IEffectVisitor<obj> with
                member this.VisitOutput x = 
                    failwith ""
                member this.VisitParallel x =                     
                    (x.Eff1.Accept(this), x.Eff2.Accept(this))
                member this.VisitReturn x = 
                    x.Value
                member __.VisitInput x = 
                    failwith ""
                    }) :?> 'a

    let foo() = 
        let x = Parallel(Return 1, Return "a")
        printfn "%A" <| NaiveEval(x)
        ()
```

Comment: Hi MrD! Looks very promising Thanks a lot. A question: how would I be able to implement the Return effect such that it actually returns the 'a value as a result? i.e. member __.Return(value) = value, however that doesn't work.

Comment: ah good point...let me take a look

Comment: I'm stuck doing a typesafe version but let me add a non typesafe version

Comment: and I actually havent run the code at any point!...so you'll have to tell me if the cast actually is valid...it looks like its correct